# How to subset raster data based on another dataset in google earth engine

Tags: javascript, gis, google-earth-engine

I am trying to subset raster A (Global Aboveground and Belowground Biomass Carbon Density Maps), which is an image collection to only keep raster values that have at least some intersection with table B, my own data, which is a feature collection. So far I have tried to use the clip and ClipToFeature functions. However these do not work as they don’t keep the raster data that exists outside the bounds of table B. I want to make it so that any raster box that overlaps with B is kept. This is my code so far:

```
var clipImage = function(image) {
  return image.clip(dataA);
};

// Map the clip function over the entire ImageCollection
var clippedRasters = dataB.map(clipImage);

Map.addLayer(clippedRasters);
```